# SQL to select a new column based on certain conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, netezza

Please help me create a SQL to generate column3 based on the following conditions

- The value of column3 must start with 1
- Whenever the value of Column2 is 'N', value of Column3 must be 1 added to value of Column3 in previous row.
- Whenever the value of Column2 is 'Y', value of Column3 must be same as that of the value of Column3 in previous row
- Whenever the value of Column1 changes, the value of Column3 must reset to 1

Data sample:

[image]

Thanks
Teresa

Comment: Order of rows, if you don't set it with `order by` clause, may be random

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

### DDL

```
create table so (
  id int
  ,column1 int
  ,column2 varchar(1)
);

insert into so values
  (1, 1, 'Y')
  ,(2, 1, 'Y')
  ,(3, 1, 'N')
  ,(4, 1, 'N')
  ,(5, 1, 'Y')
  ,(6, 1, 'Y')
  ,(7, 1, 'Y')
  ,(8, 1, 'Y')
  ,(9, 2, 'Y')
  ,(10, 2, 'Y')
  ,(11, 2, 'N');
```

### Column3 Build

```
with str as (
  select
    *
    ,min(id) over (partition by column1) id_start
    ,case column2
      when 'N' 
        then row_number() over (
          partition by column1 
          order by column2, id
        ) 
      else null
    end n_value
  from
    so
), cls as (
  select
    *
    ,case
      when id_start = id 
        then 1
      else 
        coalesce(max(n_value) over (
          partition by column1
          order by id
          rows between unbounded preceding and current row
        ) + 1 ,1)
    end column3
  from
    str
)
select
  id
  ,column1
  ,column2
  ,column3
from 
  cls
order by 
  id
```

## Explanation

You need an ordering key to make this successful, as indicated in other comments and answers. I artificially created one in the DDL, though you could certainly build another one yourself using `row_number()` and a different ordering key.

The `str` CTE in the answer provides two very critical columns that extract implicit data from the ordering: `id_start` and `n_value`.

`id_start`: Provides the ordering key value, `id`, where each `column1` changes. In your definition of `column3`, this is essentially your third bullet.

`n_value`: We need to know the number of times that the value of `column3` changes. By your definition, this only happens when `column2 = 'N'`, so this column returns the number of times that this happens within a `column1` partition.

Once we have these two pieces of data, avoiding iteration for this problem is pretty simple: `column3` is the maximum value of all previous `n_value`s plus one. The one exception to this is when a Y immediately follows the start of a partition, in which case `column3` is always 1. (This is solved with a coalesce.)

Here's a [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/034e4/1) using PostgreSQL. Netezza is a variant, so the syntax will still work there.